# My javascript Isn't updating my node value in my html

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to replace the 'Click Me!' text value in the p tags with my javascript. The script should run when the div element is clicked. Why isn't it working?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
            <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Index.css'>
            </head>
            <body>
                    <h1 id="englishHeader">English Quotes</h1>
                    <div id="inputBox" onclick = onclick()>
            <p>Click Me!</p
        </div>
            </body>

    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    </html>
<script>

    function onclick(){
    //var quotes += quotes[i]
            var itemTwo = document.getElementById('inputBox');
            var txt = itemTwo.firstChild.nodeValue;
            txt = txt.replace('Click Me!', 'Hello there');
            itemTwo.firstChild.nodeValue = txt;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: why did you added jQuery if not using ?? It will be much simpler if you use such.

Comment: Fix your HTML by using an HTML validator (e.g. quotes around the onclick attribute value, closing </p> tag, <script> outside body and html). Rename the `onclick()` function to something else, because the name is in conflict with the div's `onclick` attribute. Instead of `firstChild.nodeValue` use `textContent`.

Comment: I wouldn't get into the habit of naming functions after native JavaScript event handlers

Answer (score 0):

The first child of the div is the *TextNode* containing spaces and new lines that appear between the start of the `div` and the start of the `p`.

There is no text *Click Me!* there to replace.

You need to select the first child of *paragraph* and not the div.

Comment: var itemTwo = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); would this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, your HTML is poorly constructed and naming your function "onclick" is a really bad idea.

You've also written JavaScript that is more complicated than it needs to be, for such a simple operation.

Here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="englishHeader">English Quotes</h1>

  <div id="inputBox">
    <p id="changeMe">Click Me!</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    let div = document.getElementById('inputBox');

    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let p = document.getElementById('changeMe');
        p.textContent = 'Hello there';
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are certainly other approaches that could be taken, but this is one (relatively easy) way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
             <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Index.css'>
        </head>
        <body>
           <h1 id="englishHeader">English Quotes</h1>
          <div id="inputBox" onclick="onpclick()"><p>Click Me!</p>
          </div>
         </body>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>
function onpclick()
{
  var itemTwo = document.getElementById('inputBox');
  var txt = itemTwo.firstChild.innerHTML;
  txt = txt.replace('Click Me!', 'Hello there');
  itemTwo.firstChild.innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</html>
```

1. use innerHTML instead of nodevalue.
2. function name should not be onlclick..I have changed it to onpclick.
3. p tag was not properly ended.
4. p should be on same line to be first child of div.otherwise new line or blank spaces will be considered as first child.

Answer (score 0):

Try using itemtwo.childNodes[0].outerText to get and set

tag without using I'd attribute. But I thing using id would be the best idea.